# sharepoint 2010 and ajax issue

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have a aspx page in the _layouts directory.  I have a

The webmethod gets called fine and returns a string (string of the options that will fill another drop down) but when i return to ajax it errors out on me.

How come i can not get the string out of the returned data?  I have tried

- data.d
- var obj = parseJSON(data); then working with obj.d

client code that calls the web method

```
        function ProgramDropDown_OnChange() {
        var selectedProgram = $("#<%= ddlProgram.ClientID %>").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: '{"selectedProgram":"' + selectedProgram + '"}',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'Sdrl.aspx/ProgramDropDown_OnChange',
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#myInfoMessage").html("success: " + obj.d);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#myInfoMessage").html("failure: " + data.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
```

error message is syntax error in jquery-1.9.1.min.js

now if i change the web method to return an object (anonymous type)

```
return new { DropDownData = myOptionsString };
```

then my client code changes to

```
        function ProgramDropDown_OnChange() {
        var selectedProgram = $("#<%= ddlProgram.ClientID %>").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: '{"selectedProgram":"' + selectedProgram + '"}',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'Sdrl.aspx/ProgramDropDown_OnChange',
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#myInfoMessage").html("success: " + obj.d["DropDownData"]);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#myInfoMessage").html("failure: " + data.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
```

i get the same error message above.  same thing if i try obj.d
now if i remove the $.parseJSON and just try data, i receive [object, object]

Comment: What about using Fiddler to see what's passing over the wire?

Comment: i didn't think yoo use fiddler, great idea.  I used Firebug and needless to say i think it was an SharePoint caching issue.  Cause the code i tested the yesterday that didn't work, is working.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

might have been a SHarepoint caching issue because the code works fine this morning.